# Ultimo precio de cada producto

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas, una de productos y otra de precios, según mis requerimientos un producto puede tener muchos precios a lo largo del tiempo en distintas fechas, lo que quiero hacer es por cada producto me muestre el ultimo precio que se le ha asignado.

He intentando esto pero solo me devuelve un solo producto con su ultimo precio

```
    SELECT p.Nombre, p.Descripcion, p.CodigoPro, p.Stock, p.StockMinimo, prove.Nombre As Proveedor, (SELECT precios.Precio FROM precios Where precios.Fecha=(SELECT MAX(precios.Fecha) FROM precios)) AS Precio FROM productos p INNER JOIN precios on p.Idpro = precios.Idpro
INNER JOIN descuentos on p.Idpro = descuentos.Idpro INNER JOIN iva on p.Idpro = iva.Idpro
INNER JOIN proveedores AS prove ON prove.IdProve=p.IdProve WHERE p.Estado=True
GROUP by p.Nombre, p.Descripcion, p.CodigoPro, p.Stock, p.StockMinimo;
```

No encuentro la manera de poder mostrar todos los productos con su ultimo precio.

Aquí las estructuras de mis tablas

**Tabla Productos** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Tabla Precios**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar la estructura de tus tablas por favor ?

Comment: Listo, ya edité la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

He intentado esto, sin tener una tabla de referencia donde probar. La estrategia es hacer la misma consulta que la que hiciste, a excepción de los precios.
Se hacen los joins iniciales, luego se hace uno con una subconsulta que devuelve solo la lista de productos junto a la fecha máxima del precio, luego se une otra vez con la tabla de precios (lo he hecho en otra subconsulta) diciendo que solo tome los de la fecha de la subconsulta anterior.

```
SELECT p.Nombre, p.Descripcion, p.CodigoPro, p.Stock, p.StockMinimo, prove.Nombre As Proveedor, precios.Precio
FROM productos p 
INNER JOIN descuentos on p.Idpro = descuentos.Idpro 
INNER JOIN iva on p.Idpro = iva.Idpro
INNER JOIN proveedores AS prove ON prove.IdProve=p.IdProve 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Idpro, MAX(Fecha) as Fecha
    FROM precios
    GROUP BY Idpro
) precios2 on p.Idpro = precios.Idpro
inner join (
    SELECT Idpro, Precio, Fecha
    FROM precios
) precios on precios.Fecha = precios2.Fecha and precios.Idpro = precios2.Idprod
WHERE p.Estado=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria meter una subconsulta como campo que esté vinculado al producto, y que se ordene descententemente. Con el TOP 1 solo se saca el primero.

```
SELECT p.Nombre, p.Descripcion, p.CodigoPro, p.Stock, p.StockMinimo, prove.Nombre As Proveedor, (SELECT TOP 1 precios.Precio FROM precios Where precios.Idpro=p.IDpro ORDER BY fecha DESC) AS Precio 
    FROM productos p INNER JOIN precios on p.Idpro = precios.Idpro
        INNER JOIN descuentos on p.Idpro = descuentos.Idpro INNER JOIN iva on p.Idpro = iva.Idpro
        INNER JOIN proveedores AS prove ON prove.IdProve=p.IdProve WHERE p.Estado=True
        GROUP by p.Nombre, p.Descripcion, p.CodigoPro, p.Stock, p.StockMinimo;
```

Comment: Una explicación no caería mal